# Arch Linux - How to pass arguments to daemon in rc.conf

Tags: daemon, rc, archlinux

If I add a daemon to rc.conf, how can I then pass arguments to it?

Eg

`DAEMONS = (sshd mongodb ...)`

How can I pass `--replSet` to the `mongodb` daemon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you pass anything, it calls the daemon from /etc/rc.d/ so you'd edit that script with the args.

**EDIT**: here are some links that explain:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rc.conf#Daemons

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Writing_rc.d_scripts

Answer (score 3):

You should try to set this behaviour in `/etc/mongodb.conf`

Comment: Thanks @sputnick I figured that by taking a look in rc.d/mongodb where the file you mentioned was referenced.  Then I found these docs on the mongodb site which specify all the parameters one can use in a conf: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/File+Based+Configuration

Comment: This is better than modify the rc.d script while this script will be upgraded later by `pacman -Syu`

Comment: Oh.. :-(  Glad you told me that!!!